# Outlook Office 365 Three columns images scalable email

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I want to set up a three-column layout in a HTML email. It will contain an image (which I want to make scalable) on the left and right and a logo in the middle. However, Outlook doesn't accept percentage scaling with pixel height.

Is there any way to achieve this?

[image: example]

Comment: Emails clients, and outlook particuarly do not play well with anything remotely modern in CSS. Your best bet its to go old school and use `<table>`

Comment: just you know I am using table with 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

Outlook just can’t handle exact widths very well, so like Agi said, definitely use `<table>`. We can use the “hybrid” part of fluid hybrid design to constrain columns so they appear as intended. Hybrid tables are also sometimes called ghost tables, because they are invisible to clients other than Outlook for desktop. By creating a ghost table with we can force Outlook to display the columns side-by-side no matter what. Because other clients can’t “see” this code, it won’t interfere with responsive behavior.

Check out this article on how to create ghost tables. https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/using-ghost-columns-to-fix-alignment-problems-in-outlook/?utm_source=social&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_campaign=LeadGen_2019

Comment: I am using that. But I can't make the image scalable for image on the right and left of the logo. Ultimately I want to set fix width for the logo and percentage width for the sides. But outlook won't let me set percentage width and pixel height so I am stuck.